# Когда правильнее делать дамп MySQL?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, dump

Есть курсовая работа. Тема курсовой работы "Автоматизированная система ЗАГС". Ну можно сказать работу я закончил, но так как данные ЗАГСа очень важны, вот я и решил написать скрипт который сделал бы `dump` базы данных.

Когда правильнее делать `dump`? Может каждый час или после каждого рабочего дня или может после каждого изменения в базе данных?

Comment: *так как данные ЗАГСа очень важны* Они настолько важны, что Вы должны были предусмотреть подробное протоколирование действий оператора. Оно у Вас есть? Что же до периодичности - дампирование БД в этом смысле ничем не отличается от идеологии обычного резервного копирования, по которому имеются тонны подробнейших методик расчёта с обоснованиями.

Comment: Нет если честно я ничего не предусмотрел)

Comment: Готовьтесь бледно выглядеть, когда потребуется разбирать инцидент типа "Какая [censored] и когда удалила/добавила/изменила эту запись?"...

Comment: А что бы вы предложили? Можно узнать?)

Comment: Я бы предложил как минимум подробный лог действий оператора. Кто, когда, какое действие, с какими параметрами. Это позволит как минимум понять, кто и что, а также выполнить replay от предыдущего бэкапа до конкретного состояния (откат в заданную точку, а не в последний бэкап, иногда полезно) - эдакий "transaction log вучную". Формат - журнальная БД или в крайнем случае plain text (XML, JSON). Как максимум - хранение всех данных, необходимых для организации UNDO (впрочем, это - гарантированно за рамками курсовой).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть два варианта, которые вам стоит рассмотреть, если вы хотите обеспечить сохранность вашей базы данных.

1. Действительно, делать бекап базы данных. Частоту выбирать согласно тому, насколько проблемно реально потом будет восстановить данные руками либо вашими, либо персонала, введенные за текущий / предыдущий день. Но имейте ввиду, что дамп подразумевает остановку работы с базой.
2. Настроить репликацию, которая позволит иметь копию базы данных на момент отказа основного сервера. Руководств в сети полно, ищутся по запросу `mysql репликация`.

Естественно, что при желании вы можете и совместить их. При этом в случае совмещения дамп можно делать на `slave`-сервере, в таком случае отпадет необходимость останавливать работу с `master`-сервером.

Comment: Имхо, дамп репликации — лучший вариант)

Comment: Да, сейчас дополню, спасибо :)

Answer (score 3):

Обычно для значимых данных используют комбинацию из нескольких способов:

1. Бэкап базы данных. Для важных данных делают ежедневно (точнее каждую ночь, когда меньше нагрузка на базу). А в случае ЗАГСа это еще лучше, т.к. там ночью не будет никаких изменений базы.
2. Для данных, которые поступают уже после крайнего бэкапа лучше использовать временное хранилище. Т.е. при записи данных, они пишутся в основную базу и временное хранилище. Сразу после ночного бэкапа временное хранилище очищается. Репликацию использовать нужно, но она предназначена немного для другого. При падении базы да, она спасает ситуацию, но в случае неверной записи или преднамеренного изменения/удаления данных она перезапишет изменения в копии базы и информация будет безвозвратно удалена.

Comment: Репликация (как, впрочем, и мастер) может хранить полные логи запросов за последние несколько дней, откуда можно будет достать данные после удаления

Comment: @andreymal это уже вопрос удобства и квалификации людей, которые потом будут восстанавливать данные.